# How to Count No. Of Occurences after Union All

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite and figuring out to implement the following codes using Python.

The sample database table is as below:

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 |

How do I implement the Union All and to count the number of occurrences for each integer?
My code is as such below:

```
combine_query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT col1 FROM table UNION ALL SELECT col2 FROM table)"

c.execute(combine_query)

df= pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=['Integers', [Occurences])
```

| Integers | No of Occurences |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following union approach:

```sql
SELECT val, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM
(
    SELECT col1 AS val FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col2 FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY val
ORDER BY val;
```